# How can I passing Parameter angularjs factory $http and $stateParameters

Tags: angularjs

```
App.factory('menuService', function ($http) {
    var urlBase = 'Services/MenuService.asmx/GetAllMenu';
    var factory = {};
    factory.getAllMenus= function () {
        return $http.get(urlBase);
    };
    return factory;

});
```

Controller:

```
App.controller("sampleController",  function ($scope, menuService) {

    $scope.List = [];

    var menuData=function(data, status){
        $scope.List = data;

        console.log($scope.List);
    }

   menuService.getAllMenus().success(menuData);
});
```

/// Working perfect...

How can i use same service by other controller?

I've tried this one but wrong...

```
App.controller("viewDetailMenu", function ($scope, menuService, $stateParams) {

    $scope.menu = menuService.getMenu($stateParams.id);

});
```

Here I share image how it look..

Please help me!...

Comment: Your factory function is called `factory.getAllMenus` however in your second ctrl you are calling `menuService.getMenu`? which does not exist.

Comment: $scope.menu = menuService.getMenu($stateParams.id); changed  in  $scope.menu = menuService.getMenus($stateParams.id); but it doesn't work Jax. I have changed it too  $scope.menu = menuService.getMenu[$stateParams.id]; But this doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have all functions/methods defined if you want to use them. You getMenu function/method is not defined so it will generate an error. Please look at below code. You can add number of functions. You factory is share by all controllers so you can use it in any controller.

```
App.factory('menuService', function ($http) {
    var urlBase = 'Services/MenuService.asmx/GetAllMenu';
    var factory = {};
    factory.getAllMenus= function () {
        return $http.get(urlBase);
    },
    factory.getMenu=function(id){
        return $http.get(urlBase +"/ID="+ id) // write it according to your API.
    }
    return factory;

});
```

And then,

```
App.controller("viewDetailMenu", function ($scope, menuService, $stateParams) {

    $scope.menu = menuService.getMenu($stateParams.id).success(function(data,status){

    }).error(function(data,status){
    });

});
```

Comment: If it helped, mark it as an answer so other can get help through it.

Comment: Hi Micronyks 
In your suggestions  according on change parameters factory call again data from webservice or webmethod. What I mean is Firstly we called data from service and its loaded.  I want using second controller and by first loaded datalist chosen item showing in other page.